# Different access token from Facebook

Tags: java, javascript, android

I'm developing an app that uses OAuth to authenticate.

The problem is that when I try to get the access_token from facebook with passport.js (node.js) I get something different that when I try to get it with Scribe on Android. Is there any reason?

When I try with twitter the access token are the same and I can match users....

Thanks!

Comment: wondering - are you simply trying to ensure that its the same user (when you process the data on your server)?

Comment: Yes, the only thing that I though was checking oauth access_token (what worked with twitter)

Comment: are you saying the "id" value is different or just the token?  You can use the ID for ensuring that its the same user

Comment: the token is different. The id must be the same, but I want to en

Comment: to ensure a secure auth... I don't want to pass just the id to log from the android client

Comment: did you ever figure out what you were looking to do and how it was different from relying on the id coming from the oauth service?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misinterpreted the question, you can use the "id" field in the response from FB to detect whether its the same user or not (regardless of which API/language you end up using).  These IDs are unique per user and should allow you to detect whether the same user logged on via Android (Scribe) or passport.js (node).  Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, I know that's unique but cannot ensure with that that It'll be a secure login. I cannot pass just id frm client to server to authenticate. Everyone could authenticate just having the id

Comment: just curious - which ID are you referring to?  The unique key that FB sends in its response or something else?